# Сохранение размера текста при изменении его шрифта

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер!
Наверху страницы есть список ссылок-элементов, расположенных горизонтально. По умолчанию шрифт текста Arial, а при наведении на элемент меняется на Arial Black. А из-за того, что меняются шрифты, меняется размер текста и весь список сдвигается вниз.
Как можно избежать этого движения?

Comment: поместите каждую ссылку в отдельный контейнер для стабильного размера. где высота и длинна контейнера определяется какой-то функцией от размера шрифта и количества символов в линке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично у меня два варианта, оба извращённые.

1. каждую ссылку заключить в отдельный слой (`DIV`) и привязать статично (`position: relative;`) к списку.
2. подобрать такое значение в `px` на которое изменить размер (`font-size`) вместе со шрифтом.

К примеру:

```
a { 
                color: #aa0000;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 18px;
                text-decoration: none; 
}

a:hover { 
                color: #aa0000;
                font-family: "Arial Black";
                font-size: 15px;
                text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за варианты, но мне не подходит - сколько не подбирай.

Comment: Ещё вариант:  
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px;"><a> LOL1</a></div>  
<div style="position: absolute; top: 40px;"><a> LOL2</a></div>  
<div style="position: absolute; top: 70px;"><a> LOL3</a></div>  
Проблема будет только в подборе положения, но друг от друга они не зависят)

Comment: у меня список в линию

Comment: Ну тогда left вместо top

Comment: Замечу, это пример)) Ссылки нужно подгонять вручную с помощью свойств:  
**top: 0px;** или **bottom: 0px;**  
**left: 0px;** или **right: 0px;**  
Если в строку -> _top/bottom_ одинаковый  
Если в столбец -> _left/right_ одинаковый

Answer (score 0):

`letter-spacing: -1px;` - уменьшит расстояние между буквами, а вместе с этим и длину строки.

Comment: Список сдвигается вниз не из-за расстояния между буквами, а из-за того что шрифт Arial Black больше шрифта Arial. Поэтому вся конструкция ( а это строчка, не важно какой длины) чуть-чуть опускается.

Comment: ну тогда тут без наглядного примера не обойтись

Comment: у меня не достаточно уважения для того чтобы прикреплять картинки. Да и проблема потеряла актуальность.